# In Solr is it possible to only return one child document that matches the query?

Tags: search, solr, document

I have managed to add children document for my Solr Indexing logic, where the parent is an 'art' object, and the children document are the 'items', like below:

```
"response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"349",
        "key":"123",
        "item.product":"Classic Tee",
        "item.colors":["Black","White"],
        "item.sizes":["S","M","L"],
      },
      {
        "id":"350",
        "key":"321",
        "item.product":"Ringspun Tee",
        "item.colors":["Brown", "Red", "Blue"],
        "item.sizes":["XS"],
      },
      {
        "id":"348",
        "key":"abc",
        "artist":"Van Gogh",
        "art_link":"www.art.com/art.png",
        "default_item_key":"123"
       }
]}}
```

Right now if I query for "Van Gogh" I get back documents 348, 350, 349, which tells me I added children documents correctly. However, I'm lost as to how to configure what gets returned, for example, I wish to:

-Query "Van Gogh" returns ONLY the parent document, so I would NOT want documents with IDs 349 and 350 returned.

-Query "Black" and get back documents 349 and 348 ONLY.

-Query "Tee" and get back all 3 documents.

Comment: The [`childDocTransformer` (`[child ..]`) supports the `childFilter`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/transforming-result-documents.html#child-childdoctransformerfactory) property about which children to include. Is that what you need?

Comment: For some reason I can't find the jar nor ChildDocTransformerFactory using Java8 and maven...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - this would be part of the query syntax you send to Solr; there is no manual configuration from a jar.